# GCP Shared VPC : a subnet is not shared from host project to service project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running a basic test with GCP Shared VPC on my test deployment.

I would like a suggestion to see if I missed something or this is just some glitch from GCP:

- I have a Shared VPC host project and 3 service projects
- only 2 subnets over 3 are actually shown as shared on the Console and via gcloud command gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable --project [project ID] from one of the service projects

Background:

- there is no organization policy neither restriction,
- I have enabled the host project and attached first 2 service projects, everything was OK
- I granted individual subnets Compute network user roles to 2 users (that are also project owners of each service project)
- I have created a couple of new users with cloud identity in the same organization
- assigned project owner to newly created users for a new project and granted Network user for 3 shared subnets
- Consider I am using the free 300$ trial, but I don't think it would impact just one subnet over 3

Thank you

EDIT :
I tried adding network user role to the host project itself for the service project owner user and I can see all shared VPC subnets.

I think this may be a problem then of how the roles are applied (even if I verified them for each subnet) or simply a problem of subnet roles vs project roles

Comment: You don't have IP range overlapping ?

Comment: No overlaps :( in My test I deleted all default subnets and verified that too, also in that case it gives you an alert in the notifications, instead I just get nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a delay or error during the permission propagation time. Note that permission propagation is not immediate and can have a delay. You may have to wait a few minutes to see the changes reflected. The default time is 60 seconds and it can take up to [7 min](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#access_revoke)

However if the permission propagation time took more than 10 min, you may need to contact Cloud Support so they can look into the specifics of your situation, as you mentioned this can be a glitch with IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

While I added Network user role for the full host project, I kept the individual subnets Network user role assigned, and as I wrote I could see all Shared VPC host subnets. Once I removed the Network User role for the host project and left untouched the previous subnet Network user role assigned...it worked as originally intended...just like magic :)

I would categorize this as a glitch or bug in GCP Andromeda but in case you have similar or totally different experience / workaround let me know