# Unkown failure to associate VPC connector in service project with shared VPC subnet in main project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When trying to associate a VPC connector in a service project with a shared VPC subnet in another project (From the same organization) the following error appears:

```
Unknown error. Original error message: Operation failed: VPC Access did not have permission to resolve the subnet or the provided subnet does not exist.
```

We tried past what is acceptable for permission propagation as pointed in this other post:  [GCP Shared VPC : a subnet is not shared from host project to service project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693160/gcp-shared-vpc-a-subnet-is-not-shared-from-host-project-to-service-project), we definitely waited more than 20min and the error persisted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a Serverless VPC Access Connector using a Shared VPC first create the subnet in the Host Project of a Shared VPC with CIDR 28, there has to be a unique subnet for each Connector.

Then follow Googles Documentation [Configuring the host project if using Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#configure-host),  specifically the following sections.

### 1. Create Firewall Rules

we have to also create [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#firewall-rules-shared-vpc) to allow requests from the following IP ranges to reach the connector and to be reached by the connector:

**NAT ranges**
107.178.230.64/26 and
35.199.224.0/19

**Health check ranges**
130.211.0.0/22,
35.191.0.0/16 and
108.170.220.0/23

### 2. Grant Permissions

Also for each service project that will use VPC Connectors, a Shared VPC Admin must [grant the Compute Network User role](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#granting_permissions_to_service_accounts_in_your_service_projects) (**compute.networkUser**) in the host project to the service project **cloudservices** and **vpcaccess** service accounts.

Comment: this did not solve the issue for me, I get this error on the cloud run service of the host project: `Please ensure the project's service agent has the permission [vpcaccess.connectors.use] for action Connect on resource projects/my-project/locations/europe-west1/connectors/quick-desk-vpc`

Comment: Okay after 3 days on this I solved it by granting IAM permissions to `service-SERVICE_PROJECT_NUMBER@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as per this article: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc-connector-in-host-project

Comment: @zaffer can you be more specific please. Which project, the host or the service? What permissions did you add? You link doesn't directly lead to permissions info.

Comment: @Zymotik did you find a solution to the permission error Zaffer was experiencing? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @gorilla_glue This was my problem and how I fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769612/google-cloud-run-could-not-find-specified-network-to-attach-to-app

Comment: @Zymotik thanks so much for your response! I also separately figured out my issue which I've documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889386/13351293).