# Google Cloud Run: Could not find specified network to attach to app

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, connector

I have a Cloud Run container that uses a Serverless Connector to connect to a Cloud SQL instance all in the same project. This configuration works just fine.

I have moved the Cloud SQL instance to another project in the same organisation and setup a Serverless Connector there as per the instructions. I have tested this Serverless Connector with a Cloud Function in the same project that accesses the database and reports the number of rows in a table, this works without problems.

I have now updated the Cloud Run instance to point to the new connector reference. I have used the specified format: `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/europe-west3/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME`. When I release a new revision of the container, I get the error message: `"Could not find specified network to attach to app."` I see the message `"Ready condition status changed to False for Service {service name} with message: Deploying Revision."` in the Cloud Run logs for this service.

Any ideas on how to get this working please?

Documentation:

- [Configuring Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access)
- [Configure connectors in the Shared VPC host project](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/shared-vpc-host-project)

Info:

Command `gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors describe --region=europe-west3 projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/europe-west3/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME` gives the output:

```
connectedProjects:
- company-service-dev
- a-project-name
ipCidrRange: 10.8.0.0/28
machineType: f1-micro
maxInstances: 3
maxThroughput: 300
minInstances: 2
minThroughput: 200
name: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/europe-west3/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
network: company-project-servicename
state: READY
```

Answer (score 3):

The connector MUST be in the same region AND the same project as the Cloud Run service.

The wrong solution is to create a peering between the Cloud Run project VPC and the Cloud SQL project VPC. But it won't work because of network transitivity issue (CLoud SQL to Project create 1 peering and Cloud Run VPC to Project create another peering -> 2 peering in a row aren't transitive).

The correct solution is to create Shared VPC architecture to share the same VPC and therefore not to require to perform peering between project.

*Another ack exists: you can create a VPN between Cloud Run project VPC and Cloud SQL project VPC. It's ugly, but it works.*

Comment: Thank you. Have I read the docs incorrectly? It says "you can connect Cloud Run services directly to your Shared VPC network by using Serverless VPC Access", then goes on to specify a connector in Service or Host project and the advantages of each: [Connecting to a Shared VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-shared-vpc)

Comment: Did I miss the part where you say that you use a shared VPC? No worries, does it the case? In which project did you defined the serverless VPC connector? On the host project or on the service project?

Comment: Apologies, I was not clear on the VPC/Shared VPC. Am I correct to assume that with a Shared VPC in the Host project, along with a Connector in the Host project, that this would work with Cloud Run in a Service project? That is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**

**Problem:** Configuration. There was a VPC created for the Cloud SQL db to get an IP address assigned in. The Serverless Connector was created and had access to the same network. I, mistakenly, thought that was all that is needed. As @guillaume-blaquiere points out, this is for a single project only.

***To fix:*** Create a `Shared VPC` configuration in the host project. In the Google Cloud Console it was as easy as turning on Shared VPC (VPC Network > Shared VPC). Setup a configuration with pretty much the default options it gives you and then you can use the Serverless Connector reference `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/europe-west3/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME` in your Cloud Run or Cloud Functions and all works just fine!

Comment: In my case I just needed to ensure the host project (hosting the shared VPC) shares its subnets with the service project (where the Cloud Run service lives).