# Permission issue in connecting a serverless VPC connector to Cloud Run in host project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I have a service in Cloud Run in project `x` that needs to access a VM instance, which I am allowing access to using a serverless VPC connector (created in a *host* project). My problem, while following [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/shared-vpc-host-project) guide is that there appears to be a permission issue when deploying a new revision in Cloud Run (running in a *service* project):

`Please ensure the project's service agent has the permission [vpcaccess.connectors.use] for action Connect on resource projects/.../connector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to closely read the documentation found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/shared-vpc-host-project), specifically [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/shared-vpc-host-project#grant_roles_on_the_host_project) portion:

> On the host project, grant principals who deploy Cloud Run services the Serverless VPC Access Viewer (`vpcaccess.viewer`) role.
>
> 1. Open the `IAM` page.
> 2. Click the project dropdown menu and select the **host** project.
> 3. Click Add.
> 4. In the `New principals` field, enter the email address of the principal that should be able to see the connector from the service project. You can enter multiple emails in this field.
> 5. In the `Role` field, select `Serverless VPC Access Viewer`.

Looking back at the error message, it seems to suggest that the `Cloud Run` service account is having trouble accessing the VPC connector in the host project. So, by adding the Cloud Run service account from the *service project* in the host project's IAM page with the `Serverless VPC Access Viewer` permission, Cloud Run's service account was able to access the connector in an outside project, and I was able to successfully re-deploy Cloud Run using the serverless shared VPC connector.

Note that once you add this permission, in the `IAM` page the name should say something like "Google Cloud Run Service Agent for Project `SERVICE-PROJECT-ID`".